# Unable to match key in dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am having following dict specified as

```
dict1 = {('Q6', 'pic'): 'yes'}
```

I am trying to match key `Q6,pic` in the `dict1`. I am using following code

```
dict1Index = 6
key = 'Q' + str(dict1Index)
dictPicKey = key + "," + "pic"
if dictPicKey in dict1 : 

print "*****"
```

It is not matching output

Comment: What does that mean. How to match this particular key

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating a string with a comma in it. The key you are looking for is a tulple. Try this:

```
dict1Index = 6 
key = 'Q' + str(dict1Index)
dictPicKey = (key, "pic") 
if dictPicKey in dict1 : 
    print "*****"
```

Comment: I saw you just changed `,` in the answer. How does it impact the key matching

Comment: The comma tell python that the values are part of the tulple. The comma you used was just part of the string, because it was on quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following:

```
>>> type(('Q6', 'pic'))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type('Q6,pic')
<type 'str'>
>>> ('Q6', 'pic') == 'Q6,pic'
False
```

The key is a tuple, which has `"Q6"` and `"pic"` as its elements, and **not** the string object `"Q6,pic"`.

You should create a tuple from those strings, and only then check if it exists in the dictionary.